# Как возвратить ответ с сервлета в запрашивающий JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlet

Классическое CRUD веб приложение с использованием JavaScript и классов Java.

На пользовательской странице `index.jsp` скриптом отправляю запрос на сервер в виде обычной строки.

**JavaScript на `index.jsp`:**

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello";
    }
};
xhttp.open("POST", 'Servlet', true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("val="+ val);
<p id="demo"></p>
```

В сервлете перехватываю запрос `String active = request.getParameter("val");`, передаю в бизнес, бизнес отрабатывает и возвращает, к примеру, список пользователей. Трудность заключается в том, как теперь возвратить ответ скрипту? Это делается файлом XML или есть и другие способы?

P.S. Обращаю внимание, что запрос был выбран именно `XMLHttpRequest` из-за  модели AJAX. Не нужна перезагрузка страницы или переход в другое окно.

Comment: покажите контроллер (сервлет)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вы хотите понять как фронту получать данные из бэка.

В простейшем случаее хватает [request-response модели](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request%E2%80%93response). Если в двух словах: вы делаете запрос с фронта, бэк как-то обрабатывает этот запрос и возвращает этот результат.

Бывает так, что фронту нужно получить данные из бэка не сразу после запроса, а через какое-то время. Для этого в простейшем случае делается повторные запрос на бэк и читает ответ от сервера.

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038901/how-to-get-the-response-of-xmlhttprequest), например, можно посмотреть пример того как это делается с помощью `JavaScript`.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте сервлет с методом `doGet()`, который выглядит следующим образом:

```
 @Override
 protected void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     String text = "какой-то текст html, к примеру, список пользователей";

     response.setContentType ("text/plain");  // Устанавливаем тип содержимого ответа, чтобы js знал, чего ожидать.
     response.setCharacterEncoding ("UTF-8");  // Вы хотите русские буквы?
     response.getWriter().write(text);  // Записываем тело ответа.
 }
```

Сопоставьте этот сервлет с шаблоном URL-адреса `/Servlet` или `/Servlet/*`, как показано ниже (очевидно, шаблон URL-адреса свободен по вашему выбору, но вам нужно будет соответственно изменить URL-адрес `Servlet` в примерах кода JS повсюду):

```java
 package com.example;

 @WebServlet ("/Servlet/*")
 public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
     // ...
 }
```

Или, если вы еще не используете контейнер, совместимый с Servlet 3.0, то замените его в `web.xml` старым способом:

```xml
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.example.Servlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/Servlet/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Теперь откройте `http://localhost:8080/app/` в браузере.  Вы увидите, что содержимое `<p>` обновляется с ответом сервлета.

Comment: [Что означает если ответ "принят"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)